# Why data is not rendering into template for react and redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am new to ReactJS:

My code is :

```
class HomePage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props)
    //make this object just for testing
    this.state = {
        dataLogin : {
            age:1,
            name :'hassan',
            city : 'yaya'
         }
      }
    }

    render() {
        const { users } = this.props;
        console.log(this.props.users.items);//Line 1
        console.log(this.props.users.items.name);//Line 2
        console.log('test object state', this.state.dataLogin);//Line 4
        return (
            <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <h1>Hi {users.name}!</h1><!--Line 3-->
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { users } = state;
    return {
        users
    };
}
```

For Reducer code:

```
export function users(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SUCCESS':
      return {
        items: action.users
      };
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

For **LINE 1** it's showing data in console but when I try to fetch specific property as in **LINE 2** from an object it generates an error and also rendering data into the template for **LINE 3**.
For **LINE 1** data is :

```
{id: 3, name: "ahsan", email: "ahsan@gmail.com", age: 55, country: "pdf", …}
```

[image]

For **LINE 2** error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
```

For **Line 4**

[image]

And when I access its key like name or age it renders perfectly.

I am new to ReactJS and I am following this tutorial

http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/09/16/react-redux-user-registration-and-login-tutorial-example#users-reducer-js

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to make sure you're grabbing an index in the array `this.props.users.items[0].name` or key from an object if it's an object `this.props.users.items['Some Key'].name`

Comment: Please add you code as a whole not as separate lines. You are getting `users` and it contains `items` which it seems being a single objects. But you are trying to render `users.name` in your render method.

Comment: @FernandoAvalos 'items' is already a key.

Comment: @devserkan i have update my code and items is key which is return from reducer.

Comment: Can we see your `users` shape?

Comment: @devserkan I have image please take a look on shape of users.

Comment: So, you have one single `items` object in your `users`? Then what happens when you try to render it like that: `<h1>Hi {users.items.name}!</h1>`

Comment: @hu7sy, this bug is kinda weird, can you try destructing the object? Also are you resetting the prop anywhere else? So it's successful on the first render but fails on rerender?

`const { users: { items: { name } } } = this.props; console.log(name);`
How many times is console.log being fired?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this

```
export function users(state = {}, action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'SUCCESS':
          return {
            ...state
            users: action.users
          };
        default:
          return state
      }
    }
```

Comment: after implementing this code object is like:
users:
 data:
  age:55
  city:"apple222"
  country:"pdf"
  created_at:"2018-07-10 13:05:24"
  email:"ahsan@gmail.com"
  id:3
  name:"ahsan"
but still issue is there now when i access data key is gives an error.